# XSLT: How to move an element on its axis left/right by "n"?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm having trouble moving an element to the left (or right) on its own axis in an existing XML file.
How many nodes the current element should be moved is defined in a `$axis-move` value.
`$axis-move` can be a negative number for move left and a positive number for move right.

Since there is no function like "move left/right by n nodes" in XSLT, I have arrived at the approach to determine the target position on the axe starting from the current parent element:

For a move left action, I count the number of predecessor siblings of the current element (`$preceding-sibling-count`).
Then I subtract the number of the value of `$axis-move` (after making it a positive number).
From this, I build an XPath. This gives me the target position on the axis based on the current element's parent.

Example for a current element that should be moved two nodes to the left and has 5 preceding-siblings:

```
$preceding-sibling-count="5"
$axis-move="-2"

$target-position="$preceding-sibling-count - ($axis-move * -1)"
→ resolved: $target-position="3"

$insert-after="parent::*/*[position()=$target-position]"
→ resolved: $insert-after="parent::*/*[position()=3]"
```

Given the following XML:

```
<root>
   <p>foo 1</p>
   <p>foo 2</p>
   <p>foo 3</p>
   <p>foo 4</p>
   <p>foo 5</p>
   <moveMe>Hello World!</moveMe> <!-- current element -->
</root>
```

`<moveMe />` has `$preceding-siblings="5"` and `$axis-move="-2"` → `$target-position="3"` → `$insert-after="parent::*/*[position()=3]"` → `$insert-after= <p>foo 3</p>`.

Now I want to "cut and paste" the `<moveMe>` element from its current position and insert it after `parent::*/*[position() = 3]` (that is, after `<p>foo 3</p>`). The result should accordingly look like this:

```
<root>
   <p>foo 1</p>
   <p>foo 2</p>
   <p>foo 3</p> <!-- $insert-after="3" -->
   <moveMe>Hello World!</moveMe> <!-- new position -->
   <p>foo 4</p>
   <p>foo 5</p>
</root>
```

My current XSLT looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

   <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" />

   <xsl:template match="*" name="move-element">
      <!-- get the current element's name -->
      <xsl:variable name="current-element" select="local-name()" />
      <!-- create $MoveRule for $current-element -->
      <xsl:variable name="MoveRule" select="doc('config.xml')/matches[source = $current-element]" />
      <!--
         $axis-move defines the value by how much an element should be moved:
         negative value: move left.
         positive value: move right.
      -->
      <xsl:variable name="axis-move" select="-3" />
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="MoveRule">
            <xsl:choose>

               <!-- for moving an element to the left -->
               <xsl:when test="$axis-move lt 0">
                  <xsl:variable name="preceding-sibling-count" select="count(preceding-sibling::*)" />
                  <xsl:variable name="target-position" select="$preceding-sibling-count - ($axis-move * -1)" />
                  <xsl:variable name="insert-after" select="parent::*/*[position() = $target-position]" />
                  
                  <!-- How do I select the $insert-after element,
                       and insert the current element right of it? -->
                  
               </xsl:when>

               <!-- for moving an element to the right -->
               <xsl:when test="$axis-move gt 0">
                  <xsl:variable name="preceding-sibling-count" select="count(preceding-sibling::*)" />
                  <xsl:variable name="target-position" select="$preceding-sibling-count - ($axis-move)" />
                  <xsl:variable name="insert-after" select="parent::*/*[position() = $target-position]" />
                  <!-- How do I select the $insert-after element,
                       and insert the current element right of it? -->
               </xsl:when>

               <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:copy>
                     <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
                  </xsl:copy>
               </xsl:otherwise>

            </xsl:choose>
         </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>

   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: There is https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-insert-before and https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-remove

Comment: It is not clear where the information which element to move and by how much is coming from, and in what form. You say "the current element" - but every element is current at some point.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: Sorry, I over simplified the XSLT:

"move by how much" is coming from the `$axis-move` variable.

Current element: the template would e.g. match for "moveMe":
```
<xsl:template match="*" name="move-element">
   <xsl:variable name="axis-move" select="-3" />
   <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="moveMe">
         <xsl:choose>

            <xsl:when test="$axis-move lt 0">
            </xsl:when>

            <xsl:when test="$axis-move gt 0">
            </xsl:when>

         </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:when>
   </xsl:choose>

</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I am afraid that's not making any sense to me. -- P.S. Please do not post code in comments. Edit your question and clarify this point.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: Yes, just noticed that code in comments does not work. I have updated the code in the question itself with comments and the part to match a certain element.

Comment: I sill don't see how the element to be moved is identified. Your test `test="moveMe"` makes no sense. Note that the move must be made from the context of the parent node; by the time the processor gets to applying a template to the moved element, its position in the output is already determined. It seems you could do simply by sorting the child elements by their original position + if (??) then move-amount. But that's just guessing.

Comment: I’m parsing an external config file with all kinds of definitions of what to do with specific elements and attributes in an incoming XML. We assume that `test="moveMe"` has returned `true` for the current element (the current element’s name matches an entry in the config file).
 
All that works fine, and we can assume that the current element is known when we enter `<xsl:when test="$axis-move lt 0">` (in the XML example given in my question, that would be the element `<matchMe>`).
 
I have updated the code in the question and hope that it makes more sense now.

Comment: No,  it makes no sense to me and it does not allow me to reproduce the problem - see: [mcve] . And, as I said, you cannot execute the move from a template matching the element to be moved.

Answer (score 0):

For a single shot (i.e. move that one element left) code like

```
  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:sequence
        select="let $childElements := *,
                    $element := moveMe,
                    $pos := index-of($childElements!generate-id(), generate-id($element))
                return insert-before($childElements, $pos - 2, $element) => remove($pos + 1)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

might do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem is defined well enough. Perhaps this (overly?) simple example can help:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="axis-move" select="-2" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:variable name="nodes" select="* except moveMe" />
        <xsl:variable name="nodes-before" select="count(moveMe/preceding-sibling::*) + $axis-move" />
        <xsl:copy-of select="$nodes[position() le $nodes-before]"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="moveMe"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$nodes[position() gt $nodes-before]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this is all done in a template matching the parent `root` element.

---

P.S. If more than one  element needs to be moved, then start by calculating the final position of all child elements. Then construct the final output by sorting the elements by the calculated positions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're working with the wrong mental model. Your thought process seems to resolve around an "in-situ update" model where elements can be inserted at arbitrary points into the result tree. That's not the way XSLT works. Although many stylesheets are structured as a recursive tree-walk over the source document, a better model is that the stylesheet structure is actually isomorphic to the result tree: if you must have a sequential view of it, then the sequence of activity is based on "what is the next thing that needs to be written to the result?".

In particular, the idea that when you can encounter a particular element in the source document you can insert it into the result tree prior to elements that you have already added to the result is quite mistaken.

What you can do is, while processing the parent element (your `<root>` element), create a variable that contains a list (sequence) of the children, then manipulate this list so the children are in a different order, then write out the contents of the list to the result tree. I haven't been able to follow your exact logic, but if `$children` is the list of children, $moveMe is the element you want to move, and `$newPos` is the position you want to move it to, then you can do

```
$children[not(. is $moveMe)] => insert-before($newPos, $moveMe)
```

to create the new list. In more detail:

```
<xsl:template match="root">
 <root>
  <xsl:copy-of select="$children[not(. is $moveMe)] 
               => insert-before($newPos, $moveMe)"/>
 </root>
</xsl:template>
```